# Is there any similar method of "if __name__ == '__main__':" in julia?

Tags: python, julia

In python, the code "if **name** == '**main**" is very useful. So, I am wondering, is there any similar ways to have the same goal in Julia language?

Answer (score 2):

see the nice documentation:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#man-scripting

quoting:

> **Scripting**
>
> How do I check if the current file is being run as the main script?
> When a file is run as the main script using julia file.jl one might want
> to activate extra functionality like command line argument handling. A
> way to determine that a file is run in this fashion is to check if
>
> ```
> abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__ is true.
> ```